# How can I format and isolate specific text in a file in C# for a high score system in Visual Studio console?

Tags: c#, .net-core

## I would like to append different text in my file separately and display the text in a certain way.

You'll have to bear with me since I'm a fairly new programmer and this is also my first ever question on this site, so i might ramble a bit.

The program i'm making is for a simple quiz based in the console of Visual Studio (.NET framework, C#). I would like to have a high score function that saves, and while I have most of the code complete for it, i'm struggling with working out how to separately edit separate text in the document and having it display in the way i desire.

The only code i have written for it so far is this:

```cs
            string text = File.ReadAllText(highscorefile);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
```

The highscore system i have in place is very basic; the user inputs their name and it's saved so that would be part of it, and also the percentage score (a single integer) i'd like to include as well. I've got everything set up except the code for the text file itself.

I was wondering;

- How should i format the text in the file for it to be appendable easiest?
- How do i isolate specific parts of the text in the file so that the program appends what i want it to?
- How would i then display that code in the way i want?

Comment: i suggest checking out yaml or XML files. You can find serializers/deserializers and examples for them everywhere in the internet

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use json serialization, create a high score class, something like

```
public class HighScore{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Score {get;set;}
    public DateTime Timestamp {get;set;}
}
```

Then call the json library to [serialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0) a list of objects:

```
var highScores = new List<HighScore>(){...};
using var fileStream = File.Create(fileName);
await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(fileStream , highScores );
await fileStream.DisposeAsync();
```

Convert the file back to objects using `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<HighScore>>(fileStream)`

The benefit of this is that it is easy and reliable, the difficult details of converting text to objects is handled by the library. Json is popular, but there are plenty of alternatives, xml, yaml, protobuf, etc. They are all used in more or less the same way.

This example show how to serialize all of the objects at once, and that will work just fine if you have only a few high scores to keep track of. If you have a lot of high scores, say millions, you might want to consider some other alternative, probably a database.